# Precisión of the numbers inside a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to become a List like this

```
list={1.34,2.64,5.098,6.432}
```

in a list where the numbers have precision of one digit, like this

```
list={1.3,2.6,5.1,6.4}
```

I tried with the Function N but it did not work out. ¿What can I make it?

Comment: `list2 = Round[list, 0.1]`

Answer (score 2):

The function Numberform will do it. Try:

`Numberform[list,2]`

you should get the result you wanted. The second argument of the function is the number of digits you want.